# estimateGas works on Truffle, but fails on geth

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, contract-deployment

I'm trying to estimate the gas required for deploying a smart contract. It works fine in Truffle, but fails in Geth for some weird reason:

```
truffle(develop)> await web3.eth.estimateGas({ data: '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' })
376034
```

```
> web3.eth.estimateGas({ data: '0x608060...
Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000000) or always failing transaction
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Deploying the contract works fine, it's just estimateGas that's glitching. Would anyone know what the issue is, here?

Comment: How did you generate the bytecode? what is your solc version? What is your geth genesis file? It is possible that your geth instance doesn't have enabled some opcodes and it will fail because of that.